# Threading issue when try to consume from RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, rabbitmq

I have Code for Consumer:

```
class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,rabbitMQUrl,dgraphUrl):
        super(JaqlConsumer, self).__init__()
        self.parameters = pika.URLParameters(rabbitMQUrl)

    def run(self):    
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(self.parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange='publish', exchange_type='topic')
        result = self.channel.queue_declare('', exclusive=True)
        queue_name = result.method.queue
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange='publish', queue=queue_name, routing_key='#')
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=LIMIT)

    def process(values):
        print ("Process:" + str(len(values)))

    def on_message_callback(chan, method_frame, _header_frame, body, userdata=None):
        data = json.loads(body)
        self.values.append(data)
        if (len(self.values) >= LIMIT):
            process(self.values)
            self.values = []
            chan.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag,multiple=True)

    self.consumer_tag = self.channel.basic_consume(
        queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=on_message_callback)

    self.channel.start_consuming()

    def close(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'channel'):
            self.channel.basic_cancel(self.consumer_tag)
        if hasattr(self, 'connection'):
            if not self.connection.is_closed:
                self.connection.close()
```

Now here is my **main**.py. I'm trying to listening to ZK node, And When value change from false to true I want to consume from RabbitMQ, and from True to false I don't want to be connected to RabbitMQ:

```
    consumer = Consumer(brokerUrl)
consumer.setDaemon(True)
def toggleEnabled():
    # Get the enabled value from ZK and watch the next change
    isEnabled = config.get("enabled",enable_watch)
    print (isEnabled)
    if isEnabled:
        consumer = Consumer(brokerUrl,dgraphUrl)
        consumer.setDaemon(True)
        consumer.run()
    else:
        consumer.close()

def enable_watch(event):
    toggleEnabled()

toggleEnabled()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

The main problem is that after one toggle, The toggle code won't run and I think it's because the current thread is the consume of RabbitMQ (This what I see when I pause my script). What is the right design for toggling from main thread to another thread?

Comment: You've got a few print statements, could you show the output and describe what you expected?

Comment: hmm Basiclly when going from Enabled -> Disabled -> Enabled, I can't disable (I put breakpoint in the line of toggle and it won't break even the value in the ZK changed). When I pause I see the line is on start_consume

Comment: does the program throw an exception ?

Comment: no, The watch function just not triggered

Answer (score 0):

from my Experience, sooner or later you will run into Problems using pika and Multithreading. I'm not sure from your Implementation details and how you are using Multithreading exactly but I had also this Problem using Pika and I will try to tell you what helped me to get around this. Pika is not thread safe so you cannot use Multithreading with pika if you want to share channels between threads. here is a link to a similar Discussion about this topic on github: [here](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/828)

so if you want anyway to use Multithreading and with pika so my Advice to you is to use Multiprocessing or to use a new Connection for every Thread. So that every Thread will have an independent Connection. It's not efficient but that's the only alternative for now I think.

Comment: I don't really want multithreading. At the beginning my consumer code was on the same thread, but then the ZK watch function didn't worked and I thought it because everything is on the same thread - so the pika consume blocks the thread. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Shkolar does your Program throws an Error ? if yes can you show the traceback

Comment: @Shkolar if it is on the same thread, it will work fine but as soon as you start using multithreading, that means when you assign a n independent thread for every task or every subscriber then you will start having problems because you cant share channels between threads

Comment: There is no error, The watch function is simply don't called.
I don't mind to be on the same thread, but again, the watch is not working when it's on the same thread

Comment: `Pika is not thread safe so you cannot use Multithreading with pika.` That is an incorrect statement. You have to know what you're doing, but you can use Pika with threads. The best way is to create a connection per-thread.

Comment: @LukeBakken yes you are right, although I already explained later that it is possible to use a Connection per Thread or Multiprocessing, but yes the sentence is False without saying that it is not possible only if someone want to share connection between threads.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be part of your `run()` method:

```
self.consumer_tag = self.channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=on_message_callback)

self.channel.start_consuming()
```

Did you make an error when you pasted your code into your question?

I suggest adding your code to a GitHub repository or gist. Then, ask your question on the [`pika-python`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/pika-python) mailing list and I will continue to assist there. Stack Overflow is not a good venue for back-and-forth assistance.